# Iterating operations over unique values of an array

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, pandas, iterator

I have a pandas dataframe that resembles one generated as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x0 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(10, 4)))
x1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,1,2,3,2,3,4,1,2,3]})
df = pd.concat((x0, x1), axis=1)
```

and a function:

```
def fun(df, n=100):
    z = np.random.normal(size=n)    
    return np.dot(df[[0,1,2,3]], [0.5*z,-1*z,0.3*z,1.2*z])
```

I would like to:

- use identical draws `z` for each unique value in `x`,
- take the product of the output in the above step over items of unique `x`

Any suggestion?

**Explanation**:

1. Generate `n=100` draws to get `z` such that `len(z)=100`
2. For each `elem` in `z`, evaluate the function `fun`,
3. For `i` in `df.x.unique()`, compute the product of the output in step (2) element-wise. I am expecting to get a DataFrame or array of dimension (len(df.x.unique(), n=100)
  4.

Comment: So my understanding of your question for each unique value of x you want the same z normal random distribution, you then want to use that distribution to produce a different np.dot for each unique value?

Comment: Could you confirm if the following does what you want: `z = dict(zip(df.x.unique(), np.random.normal(size=100)))
def fun(df, n=100):
    return np.dot(df[[0,1,2,3]], [0.5*z[df.x],-1*z[df.x],0.3*z[df.x],1.2*z[df.x]])
df.apply(fun, axis=1)`

Comment: Well you're going to have to explain better with concrete values and desired output then

Comment: @EdChum I hope it is clearer with my edits

Comment: @EdChum `zip` with `dict` returns only one of arrays associated with  a unique `x`, `list` returns all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to group by 'x', taking one of its instances (let's assume we take the first one observed).

just call your function as follows:

```
f = fun(df.groupby('x').first())

>>> f.shape
Out[25]: (4, 100)

>>> len(df.x.unique()
Out[26]:  4
```